# Removing punctuation using sed

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to write a script that removes punctuation from a text file.

I tried using sed, however am open to other suggestions (like awk)

This is my code so far

```
declare -a marks=('\.' '\,' '\;' '\:')

for i in {0..3}
do
    sed -i 's/${marks[i]}//g' test.txt
done
cat test.txt`
```

I think my main problem is am not using escape keys correctly.

Comment: `sed` doesn't change the file, it outputs the new version. Single quotes don't interpolate variables.

Comment: @choroba sorry I forgot to add the -i which to my understanding changes the file.
Can you suggest a fix to the variable interpolation?

Comment: The second point stands : when enclosed into single-quotes, `${marks[i]}` isn't expanded by `bash`

Comment: Instead of running `sed` several times in a loop it would be better to use a pattern that includes all characters to be removed or maybe create a pattern from your array. In your example the `sed` command could be `sed -i  's/[.,;:]//g' test.txt`

Answer (score 3):

The command `tr` is great for that:

```
tr -d '[:punct:]' < test.txt > tmp.txt && mv -f tmp.txt test.txt
```

`-d` stands for delete.

Choose a non-existing file `tmp.txt`; to generate a temporary file a solution is `mktemp -u`.

Here is a small script which removes any punctuation in the files passed as arguments:

```
#! /bin/bash
t=$(mktemp -u)
for f ; do
    tr -d '[:punct:]' < "$f" > "$t" && mv -f "$t" "$f"
done
```

`for f` is a shortcut for `for f in "$@"`, which iterates over each argument without word splitting.

Comment: When you need to replace single characters with single character or remove single characters, tr if a better solution. Kudos.

Comment: Curious: why do you use `-u` with `mktemp`?

Comment: There is also [`sponge`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?apropos=0&q=sponge&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html) from the `moreutils` package

Comment: I use '-u' to ask `mktemp` a random temporary path without creating a file, which would be otherwise immediately overwritten by `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ed` instead:

```sh
printf "%s\n" 'g/[[:punct:]]/s/[[:punct:]]//g' w  | ed -s test.txt
```

removes all punctuation characters from a file and saves the remaining text.